# Как правильно загрузить файл с помощью COPY FROM?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql9.5

```
COPY tmp FROM '‪‪C:\temp\ls.xls';
```

Выходит ошибка

> [Err] ОШИБКА:  не удалось открыть файл "‪‪C:\temp\ls.xls" для чтения: Нет такого файла или каталога

Comment: А документацию нынче читать не модно, не молодёжно? [Пользователям Windows следует использовать формат E'' и продублировать каждую обратную черту в пути файла.](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/sql-copy)

Comment: Покажите на примере, пожалуйста.

Документацию читала.

Comment: *Документацию читала* -- тогда внесите изменения в вопрос, сейчас он не соответствует сути проблемы.

Comment: 1) что такое формат E''?
2) ошибка та же.

Comment: COPY tmp FROM '‪‪C:‪‪\\temp\\ls';

Comment: [Err] ОШИБКА:  не удалось открыть файл "C:‪‪\\temp\\ls" для чтения: Нет такого файла или каталога

Comment: Ещё раз: [читать документацию](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/datatype-binary)

Comment: @Елена а вы расширение все же добавьте наверное

Comment: @rjhdby , пробовала. И слэш в другую сторону писать тоже пробовала. 

[SQL]COPY tmp FROM '‪‪C:‪‪//temp//ls.xls';

[Err] ERROR:  could not open file "‪‪C:‪‪//temp//ls.xls" for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: @Елена А файл точно есть? Надо либо так `‪‪C:‪\\temp\\ls.xls`, либо так `‪‪C:‪‪/temp/ls.xls`. Если обратные слеши, то два, если прямые, то один

Comment: @rjhdby , файл точно есть. Возможно, Postgres смотрит не на диск С.
Буду уточнять, большое спасибо!